# macdeployqt ERROR: Cannot resolve rpath "QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui (compatibility version 5.5.0, current version 5.5.0)"

Tags: qt, rpath, otool, macdeployqt

I use qmake to compile my Qt Application project on my MacBook.
It need a dylib called `libcore.dylib`, and I put it into dir `$$OUT_PWD/../libs`.
for compile, I add this code in `.pro` file

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../libs/release
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../libs/debug
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../libs
LIBS += -lcore
```

for running, I add

```
macx {
    QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl,-rpath,$$OUT_PWD/../libs
}
```

to compile `libcore.dylib`, I add

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): DESTDIR = $$OUT_PWD/../libs/release
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): DESTDIR = $$OUT_PWD/../libs/debug
else:unix: DESTDIR = $$OUT_PWD/../libs
macx {
    QMAKE_SONAME_PREFIX = @rpath
}
```

After this done, I can run the generated app directly.
But when I deploy the app using `macdeployqt`, errors occur.

```
ERROR: Cannot resolve rpath "QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui (compatibility version 5.5.0, current version 5.5.0)"
ERROR:  using QSet("/Users/sjchao/Documents/QtBuild/project/debug/app/../libs")
ERROR: Cannot resolve rpath "QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (compatibility version 5.5.0, current version 5.5.0)"
ERROR:  using QSet("/Users/sjchao/Documents/QtBuild/project/debug/app/../libs")
ERROR: Cannot resolve rpath "QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui (compatibility version 5.5.0, current version 5.5.0)"
ERROR:  using QSet("/Users/sjchao/Documents/QtBuild/project/debug/app/../libs")
ERROR: Cannot resolve rpath "QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (compatibility version 5.5.0, current version 5.5.0)"
ERROR:  using QSet("/Users/sjchao/Documents/QtBuild/project/debug/app/../libs")
ERROR: Cannot resolve rpath "QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork (compatibility version 5.5.0, current version 5.5.0)"
ERROR:  using QSet("/Users/sjchao/Documents/QtBuild/project/debug/app/../libs")
```

The QSet of rpaths did not contain  `/Users/sjchao/Applications/Qt/5.5/clang_64/lib` !
But the final compile cmd contains `-Wl,-rpath,/Users/sjchao/Applications/Qt/5.5/clang_64/lib` ! It's **useless**?
I saw a little `macdeployqt` source [shared.cpp](http://fossies.org/linux/misc/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0.tar.gz/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/qttools/src/macdeployqt/shared/shared.cpp), then 
I use `otool -l` to see `LC_RPATH`

```
Load command 27
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 112
         path /Users/sjchao/Documents/QtBuild/project/debug/app/../libs (offset 12)
Load command 28
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 64
         path /Users/sjchao/Applications/Qt/5.5/clang_64/lib (offset 12)
```

See some code in [shared.cpp](http://fossies.org/linux/misc/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0.tar.gz/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/qttools/src/macdeployqt/shared/shared.cpp)

```
426     while (i.hasNext()) {
427         if (i.next().contains("cmd LC_RPATH") && i.hasNext() &&
428         i.next().contains("cmdsize") && i.hasNext()) {
429             const QString &rpathCmd = i.next();
430             int pathStart = rpathCmd.indexOf("path ");
431             int pathEnd = rpathCmd.indexOf(" (");
432             if (pathStart >= 0 && pathEnd >= 0 && pathStart < pathEnd) {
433                 QString rpath = rpathCmd.mid(pathStart + 5, pathEnd - pathStart - 5);
434                 if (resolve) {
435                     rpaths << resolveDyldPrefix(rpath, path, executablePath);
436                 } else {
437                     rpaths << rpath;
438                 }
439             }
440         }
441     }
```

Run this code with the `LC_RPATH`, `rpaths` should contains `/Users/sjchao/Applications/Qt/5.5/clang_64/lib`, but the error msg said no.
My Qt version is 5.5.0, and I have updated it to the lastest version using MaintenanceTool.
What should I do? Is it a bug of `macdeployqt`? Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you solve this @sjchao?